# Lower 25 bits of uint64_t

Tags: c++

I am trying to extract the lower 25 bits of `uint64_t` to `uint32_t`. This [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21540158/how-do-i-extract-bits-from-32-bit-number?rq=1) shows how to extract lower 16 bits from `uint32_t`, but I am not able to figure out for `uint64_t`. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `uint32_t foo = someInt64 & ((1 << 25) - 1);` or `uint32_t foo = someInt64 & 0x1ffffff;` This answer explains that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39258841/920069

Comment: Assuming `x` is a uint64_t, you can do `x = x ^ (x >> 25 << 25);` as a quick way to get it.  Or you can do `x = x & ((uint64_t{1} << 25) - 1);

Comment: @RetiredNinja That works !! Thanks !!

Answer (score 3):

See [How do you set, clear, and toggle a single bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47981/how-do-you-set-clear-and-toggle-a-single-bit) for bit operations.

To answer your question:

```
uint64_t lower25Bits = inputValue & (uint64_t)0x1FFFFFF;
```

Answer (score 3):

Just mask with a mask that leaves just the bits you care about.

```
uint32_t out = input & ((1UL<<26)-1);
```

The idea here is: `1UL<<26` provides an (`unsigned long`, which is guaranteed to be at least 32-bit wide) integer with just the 26th bit set, i.e.

```
00000100000000000000000000000000
```

the -1 makes it become a value with all the bits below it set, i.e.:

```
00000011111111111111111111111111
```

the AND "lets through" only the bits that in the mask correspond to zero.

---

Another way is to throw away those bits with a double shift:

```
uint32_t out = (((uint32_t)input)<<7)>>7;
```

The cast to `uint32_t` makes sure we are dealing with a 32-bit wide unsigned integer; the `unsigned` part is important to get well-defined results with shifts (and bitwise operations in general), the 32 bit-wide part because we need a type with known size for this trick to work.

Let's say that `(uint32_t)input` is

```
11111111111111111111111111111111
```

we left shift it by 32-25=7; this throws away the top 7 bits

```
11111111111111111111111110000000
```

and we right-shift it back in place:

```
00000001111111111111111111111111
```

and there we go, we got just the bottom 25 bits.

Notice that the first `uint32_t` cast wouldn't be strictly necessary because you already have a known-size unsigned value; you could just do `(input<<39)>>39`, but (1) I prefer to be sure - what if tomorrow `input` becomes a type with another size/signedness? and (2) in general current CPUs are more efficient working with 32 bit integers than 64 bit integers.